# Parse data between a function in javascript using regex

Tags: javascript, regex, parentheses

I have a string like the following

> rotate(32) translate(0,-284.35468),translate(8545,84) matrix(d,f,g,s,g) translate(-58,88)

Each function can be separated by a comma or a blank space.

I want to find all the ocurrences of the information that is inside the brackets of "translate" using javascript regular expressions. So in the above example the desired result would be:

```
["0,-284.35468","8545,84","-58,88"]
```

To be more specific, I want to parse the information found in the "tranform" attribute of the "g" tag in the SVG specification. It can be found here http://www.w3.org/TR/2011/REC-SVG11-20110816/coords.html#TransformAttribute

Thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try a little something like this:

```
var s = "rotate(32) translate(0,-284.35468),translate(8545,84) matrix(d,f,g,s,g) translate(-58,88)";

var re = /translate\(([^,]+,[^)]+)\)/g,
    results = [],
    c;

while (c = re.exec(s))
    results.push(c[1]);

// results is now ["0,-284.35468", "8545,84", "-58,88"]
```

Using the [`.exec()` method](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/RegExp/exec) repeatedly on a regex that has the "g" flag will find successive matches.

In this case we're taking the second element in the array returned by `.exec()` since that will be the part of the string that matched the part of the regex in the capturing parentheses.